# Mongoose Model is Not Saving, Not Throwing Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My mongoose model (node/express app) is neither saving nor throwing an error and I do not know why...

Here is my model. It has a Post referencing many comments by schema ID:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
  body: {type: String, required: true, max: 2000},
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  flags: {type: Number, default: 0}
}, {
  writeConcern: {
    w: 0,
    j: false,
    wtimeout: 200
  }  
});

var PostSchema = new Schema({
  body: {type: String, required: true, max: 2000},
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  flags: {type: Number, default: 0},
  comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
}, {
  writeConcern: {
    w: 0,
    j: false,
    wtimeout: 200
  }  
});

var Post =  mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema)

module.exports = {
  Post: Post,
  Comment: Comment
}
```

Here is my Route. It simply creates a post from the incoming body and attempts to save it. It references the exported post by `model.Post` as the exported module is an object.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
var model = require('../models/model');

router.post('/uploadPost', (req, res, next)=>{
  console.log('inside /uploadPost')
  console.log('value of req.files: ', req.files)
  console.log('value of req.body: ', req.body)

  var post = {
    body: req.body.post, 
    created: Date.now(),
    flags: 0, 
    comments: []
  }

  console.log('value of post: ', post)

  let postInstance = new model.Post(post)

  console.log('value of postInstance: ', postInstance)

  postInstance.save().then(post=>{
    console.log('value of post: ', post)
  }).catch( (e) => {
    console.log('There was an error', e.message);
  });

  res.json({return: 'return from /uploadPost'})
})

module.exports = router;
```

And here is my terminal output. It manages to `console.log` everything with the exception of either the save callback or the error. I thought it may have been a race condition with the `res.json`, so I put that in the callback, but that didn't do anything either. What is going on?

```
value of req.body:  { post: 'lkjlkjlk' }
value of post:  { body: 'lkjlkjlk',
  created: 1552587547653,
  flags: 0,
  comments: [] }
value of postInstance:  { flags: 0,
  comments: [],
  _id: 5c8a9b1ba7cece70037d3f46,
  body: 'lkjlkjlk',
created: 2019-03-14T18:19:07.653Z }
```

EDIT:

I was connecting to mongoose wrong...sigh.

Here is a correct connection code (the above then is correct):

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
  console.log('connected to mongoose db')
});
```

Comment: Have you called `mongoose.connect` somewhere?

Comment: Thanks, I was connecting incorrectly...:/